# How could I create an array using a field id in a field form

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, field

I have a form with the following text fields that I would want to push as an array:

```
<input type="text" name="qty" placeholder="regular-price" class="ticket-quantity" id="tickets" value="1">
<input type="text" name="qty" placeholder="vip-price" class="ticket-quantity" id="tickets" value="1">
<input type="text" name="qty" placeholder="viip-price" class="ticket-quantity" id="tickets" value="1">
```

Am using this function but not getting the desired output:

```
var tickets = [];
    $.each($("input#tickets"), function(){   
    var quantity = $(this).parent().find('input.ticket-quantity').val();
    tickets.push({"tickets" : $(this).val(), "value" : quantity});
    });
    ajax_data.tickets = tickets;
```

How do I write my Javascript to pull:

```
tickets[0][ticket]  "regular-ticket"
tickets[0][value]   "2"
tickets[1][ticket]  "vip-ticket"
tickets[1][value]   "1"
tickets[2][ticket]  "viip-ticket"
tickets[2][value]   "0"
```

Comment: `id` is meant to be unique, if you need to get inputs as a group, use a common `className`.

Comment: Also this `var quantity = $(this).parent().find('input.ticket-quantity').val();` will always return the value of the first input. Why use parent here?

Comment: Kindly guide me on how I could only push fields that have a value greater than "0".